# Linux limit connections on a specific port

Tags: linux, iptables, web-server

I am following [iptables connection limits](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-connection-limits-howto/) to limit the amount of connections the server can get on port 80. For instance I tried:

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 10 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

This seems to limit connections per IP. Is there any way to via IPTables or perhaps sysctl to limit the connection amount globally. Meaning that if say host A jams up all of the 10 available sessions then no other host will be able to connect?

Comment: I know you are asking about IPTables/sysctl but just in case you hadn't thought of it, you can do this at the web server level too, in Apache/Nginx config etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify your rule by adding the option `--connlimit-mask 0`. This effectively enables you to limit connections globally and all IPs will be treated without any distinction.

On the contrary, the default value `32` for IPv4 means to match every single IP alone.

As suggested by @JayMcTee, you can use web server level solution to limit connections limit. For example, you can look at `MaxClients` option for [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html).